# Convert pixels to canvas

Tags: html, canvas

If there's an area(a custom shape) in a color(e.g. Red), is there a way to convert that red colored area to a canvas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is a bit vague, but it is impossible to have non-rectangular canvas.

Comment: Thanks @kirilloid. Just to clarify my question as it was un-clear to you. My question was, if there's an area or a shape colored in red or any other color, is it possible to convert to a canvas by reading it's pixels.

Comment: No, it is impossible to reading pixels from anything except canvas itself. There are pure js code for reading `jpg`, `png` and some other popular formats, but hardly you need them. You could just draw an image on canvas. Direct converting another elements to canvas is impossible.